# ocamlopt: option to control where to put cmx and cmi

Tags: build, ocaml

Is there a command line option or argument to ocamlopt (and ocamlc) to tell there it where to put the produced `.cmx` (and similar) files?

The documentation mentions `-o`, but that only works for me when there's no `.mli` file.

Similar for `.cmi` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-o` option works for me:

```
$ ocamlopt -version
4.03.0
$ ls
t.ml
$ ocamlopt -c -o zed.cmx t.ml
$ ls
t.ml
zed.cmi
zed.cmx
zed.o
```

Comment: I have the same ocamlopt version, but can only replicate that when there's not `.mli` file.